# Import/Export .csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I have testDates.csv with 100 dates

```
date
1/10/17
6/10/18
9/10/42
...
```

I made a script that makes sample passwords based off these dates:

```
$file = Import-Csv -Path U:\Desktop\testDates.csv

foreach ($line in $file) {
    $fullDate = $line.date
    $year = Get-Date $fullDate -Format "yy"
    $currentDate = Get-Date $fullDate -Format "MM-dd"

    # Determining season
    if ($currentDate -ge (Get-Date 01-01) -and $currentDate -lt (Get-Date 03-01)) {
        $season = "Winter"
    } elseif ($currentDate -ge (Get-Date 03-01) -and $currentDate -le (Get-Date 05-31)) {
        $season = "Spring"
    } elseif ($currentDate -ge (Get-Date 06-01) -and $currentDate -le (Get-Date 08-31)) {
        $season = "Summer"
    } elseif ($currentDate -ge (Get-Date 09-01) -and $currentDate -le (Get-Date 11-30)) {
        $season = "Fall"
    } elseif ($currentDate -ge (Get-Date 12-01) -and $currentDate -le (Get-Date 12-31)) {
        $season = "Winter"
    } else {
        $season = "ClearyAnIntern"
    }

    # Creating password
    $SamplePassword = $season + $year
}
```

I want to export the created password back to the original .csv in a new column. So have a column "passwords" next to "dates" to see if my script works correctly. Example:

```
date    password
1/10/17 Winter17
6/10/18 Summer18
9/10/42 Fall42
...     ...
```

I know it involves `Export-Csv` but I don't know how to pipe it especially for each line. I've been looking at tons of different threads and the MS help center for how to use the different parameters such as `-Append` and so forth but everything I've seen and tried isn't exactly what I'm dealing with and to infer from those examples is outside the scope of my remedial knowledge at the moment. I'm beginning to believe this may involve nested `foreach` loops.

Comment: And yes I am doing northern meteorological rather than astronomical seasons ranges. Happy summer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Csv C:\path\input.csv | ForEach-Object {
   $seasons = [Char[]]'wwsssmmmfffw' # seasons map
}{ # walk around CSV lines
   [PSCustomObject]@{
      Date = $_.date # first and second columns of future CSV
      Password = "$(switch ($seasons[([DateTime]$_.date).Month - 1]) {
         'w' {'Winter'} 's' {'Spring'} 'm' {'Summer'} 'f' {'Fall'}
      })$(Get-Date $_.date -Format yy)"
   }
} | Export-Csv C:\path\out.csv # export result
```

Comment: Love this approach.  I found to get correct results had to subtract 1 as the seasons map starts to count from 0:    `Password = "$(switch ($seasons[(get-date $_.date).Month -1]) ..`

Comment: @Itchydon Thank you for your vigilance. Updated.

Comment: A pleasure - I also found I needed to change it to     `get-date` otherwise subtracting 1 in that way from [DateTime] gives me an error

Comment: Incredible! I wish I understood how it worked though, I can't wrap my head around of how it calculates the seasons. Any recommended further reading to educate myself?

Comment: @Ryan There is no any black magic, only PS code. Each season of a year is determined by a month name or number and every season has three month, right? It's elementary logic, no more. And I do not have any idea why determining a season of a year should be sophisticated. Further reading? There is always something to learn.

Comment: @Ryan you can read further about switch statements here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch

Answer (score 3):

`Export-Csv` expects a list of objects as input, so that's what you need to create first.

```
foreach ($line in $file) {
    ...
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'     = $fullDate
        'password' = $SamplePassword
    }
}
```

Next, `foreach` loops can't write to the pipeline, so you either need to append to the output file inside the loop:

```
foreach ($line in $file) {
    ...
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'     = $fullDate
        'password' = $SamplePassword
    } | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType -Append
}
```

or collect the output in a variable and export it afterwards:

```
$list = foreach ($line in $file) {
    ...
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'     = $fullDate
        'password' = $SamplePassword
    }
}

$list | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Otherwise you need to replace the `foreach` loop with a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Desktop\testDates.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $fullDate = $_.date
    ...
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'     = $fullDate
        'password' = $SamplePassword
    }
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calculated properties](https://workingsysadmin.com/calculated-properties-in-powershell/) combined with a for loop to do so. The same is illustrated below -

```
#Importing csv dates file
$file = Import-Csv -Path U:\Desktop\testDates.csv

#Declaring the variable to store passwords
$SamplePassword = @()

#loop
foreach ($line in $file)
{
    #Variable declarations
    $fullDate = $line.date
    $year = get-date $fullDate -Format "yy"
    $currentDate = get-date $fullDate -Format "MM-dd"

    #Determining season
    if ($currentDate -ge (get-date 01-01) -and $currentDate -lt (get-date 03-01))
        {$season = "Winter"}
    elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 03-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 05-31))
        {$season = "Spring"}
    elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 06-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 08-31))
        {$season = "Summer"}
    elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 09-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 11-30))
        {$season = "Fall"}
    elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 12-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 12-31))
        {$season = "Winter"}
    else{
    $season = "ClearyAnIntern"
    }

    #Creating password
    $SamplePassword += $season + $year
}
```

After the above step, your `$SamplePassword` will contain all the passwords. Use calculated properties with a for loop as shown below -

```
#Declaring a new variable to store the results
$NewCsv = @()
$Originalcsv = Import-Csv -path U:\Desktop\testDates.csv
for($i = 0; $i -lt $Originalcsv.Length; $i++)
{
    $NewCsv += $Originalcsv[$i] | Select-Object *, @{Name='Password';Expression={$SamplePassword[$i]}}
}

$NewCsv | Export-Csv U:\Desktop\NewtestDatesWithPasswords.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

I only guess the dates in your csv file have the format `M/d/yy` ? 
Importing from csv the variable type is always string, since my own locale deviates I have to define a different culture to convert.

Using a modified version of my `function Get-Season` from your other question.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\21\SO_50976425.ps1
## define function first
Function Get-Season([datetime]$Date){
    If (!$Date) {$Date = Get-Date} #If date was not provided, assume today.
    # The dates are obviously not exactly accurate and are best guesses
    $Spring = Get-Date -Day 20 -Month 03 -Year $Date.Year
    $Summer = Get-Date -Day 21 -Month 06 -Year $Date.Year
    $Autumn = Get-Date -Day 22 -Month 09 -Year $Date.Year
    $Winter = Get-Date -Day 21 -Month 12 -Year $Date.Year
    $Season = switch($Date) {
        {($_ -lt $Spring)}  {"Winter";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Summer)}  {"Spring";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Autumn)}  {"Summer";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Winter)}  {"Autumn";Break}
        {($_ -ge $Winter)}  {"Winter"}
    }
    "{0}{1}" -f $Season,$Date.ToString('yy')
}

#Importing csv dates file
$file = Import-Csv -Path '.\testDates.csv'

# get CultureInfo
$CIUS = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

# process $file and create a new PSCustomObject
$DatePassw = foreach ($line in $file){
    $fullDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($line.date,"M/d/yy",$CIUS)
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        date     = $line.date
        password = (Get-Season $fulldate)
    }
}
$DatePassw | ft
$DatePassw | Export-Csv '.\testdatepassw.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_50976425.ps1

date    password
----    --------
1/10/17 Winter17
6/10/18 Spring18
9/10/42 Summer42

> gc .\testdatepassw.csv
"date","password"
"1/10/17","Winter17"
"6/10/18","Spring18"
"9/10/42","Summer42"
```

Comment: If you prefer `Fall` over `Autumn` simply exchange in the function. BTW september, 10th is still summer ( in the original definition) but you may change that also to your quarter definition.