# List of KB installed for Windows Updates and Last reboot Status required in one file

Tags: windows, powershell, window

I am trying to get all the list of KB installed on multiple servers and get the last reboot time of the system. My requirement is to get the result in csv or text format with column name  "Hostname" , "KB Name" , "installed by" , "installed on" and "Last reboot". I have to execute 2 script to get this done and then i have to format it and i dont want other columns which i am receiving from code 1 only limited column are required.. Can some please help me to get the same format which i reuired?

Output required in below format :

```
"Source" "Description" "HotFixID"  "InstalledBy"  "InstalledOn" "Last Reboot"
```

Please find below 2 code.

FYI : I am new to powershell.

Code 1: This will list all KB installed patch.

```
$computers = Get-Content -path "C:\Users\joy\Desktop\Machine_List.txt"
$patches = Get-Content -path "C:\Users\joy\Desktop\KB_List.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers){
 foreach ($patch in $patches){

 Get-HotFix -id $patch -ComputerName $computer | -OutVariable results -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 if ($results -ne $null) {

 $results | Out-File C:\Users\joy\Desktop\report1.txt -Append -Force

 }

 else {

 Add-content "$Patch is not Present in $computer" -path "C:\Users\joy\Desktop\report2.txt"

 }

 }
```

Code 2: This will get the last reboot of the system.

```
$machines = Get-Content C:\Users\joy\Desktop\Machine_List.txt 
$report = @() 
$object = @() 
foreach($machine in $machines) 
{ 
$machine 
$object = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $machine | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} 
$report += $object 
} 
$report | Export-csv C:\Users\joy\Desktop\Reboot.csv
```

Comment: You have most of the bits that you need in those two scripts. So the first step is to read each of those scripts one line at a time and learn what that specific line does. The take the lines that you need and start writing your own script. It is good that you have done some research but essentially you are still asking us to write the script for you. I will give you a hint that the Get-Hotfix line and the gwni line are the two lines that do the heavy lifting. Start by understanding those.

Comment: Thanks @EBGreen , I am aware of each line of code , and i am not asking to give me the code written. I need the help that i can insert two variable output in one csv format and i am unable to do .

Comment: @JoyMatt - You can make use of [Calculated properties](https://workingsysadmin.com/calculated-properties-in-powershell/), to do so. Please see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976425/import-export-csv-file/50977033#50977033). Tweaking it a bit may help in achieving your desired results.

Comment: @JoyMatt, what you need to do is to combine both pieces of information using a [PsCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation?view=powershell-6), then send these objects to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\Machine_List.txt
$patchlist = Get-Content C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\KB_List.txt
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
Get-HotFix -ComputerName $computer -Id $patchlist | select 
InstalledOn,InstalledBy,Description,HotFixID,__SERVER | Format-Table | Out-File 
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\report1.txt
#Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime | 
Format-Table |Out-File C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\report1.txt
gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computer | select csname, 
@{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} | Out- 
File C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\report1.txt -Append
}
```

Try this, This will allow you to get information what you are looking for. But this script only get installed patches information from the remote machines, If you want add one more loop to print the patches which are installed on another text file.